# Set json object's key in android

Tags: android, json

I have this json file:

```
[ { “dir radix”: [ {”dir1”:”dir”}, {”dir3”:”dir”},] },

  { “dir1”: [ {”dir11”:”dir”}, {”dir12”:”dir”}]},

  { “dir3”: []}
]
```

How can I set the key "dir radix" or the others?
I use this code to search the right key that I want to rename:

```
try {
     parse = new JSONArray(temp);
     //temp is the string returned by the reading of the file json
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
     for (i = 0; i < parse.length() && flag == 0; i++) {
         obj = parse.getJSONObject(i);                 
         Iterator iterator = obj.keys();
         while (iterator.hasNext() && flag == 0) {
             String key = (String) iterator.next();  
             //elem is the selected item that I want to rename
             if (elem.equals(key)) {
                  flag = 1;                                
                  //set json's key
             }
         }
     } 
     writefile(parse.toString(),f);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to replace json object key, so maybe you can remove object and add new object with new key. Try that code

```
        String newKey = "NEW_KEY";
        String elem = "OLD_KEY";
        String temp = "SRC_JSON";
        int flag = 0;
        JSONArray parse = new JSONArray(temp);
        //temp is the string returned by the reading of the file json
        JSONObject obj = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < parse.length() && flag == 0; i++) {
            obj = parse.getJSONObject(i);
            Iterator iterator = obj.keys();
            while (iterator.hasNext() && flag == 0) {
                String key = (String) iterator.next();
                //elem is the selected item that I want to rename
                if (elem.equals(key)) {
                    flag = 1;

                    //set json's key
                    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray(key);
                    obj.remove(key);
                    obj.put(newKey, array);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I try it and in this way It replaces exactly my old json object, this is what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

`JSONObject` in java represents a mapping, so you can't easily change a key. You can, however, remove a value and re-add that value with a different key. Here's a convenience method that can help:

```
public static void changeKey(JSONObject object, String oldKey, String newKey) throws JSONException {
    if (!object.has(oldKey)) {
        // key doesn't exist, quit early
        return;
    }
    Object oldData = object.get(oldKey);
    object.remove(oldKey);
    object.put(newKey, oldData);
}
```

And in your scenario, you no longer have to loop through the keys. You can simply call like this:

```
changeKey(obj, key, "new_key");
```

Comment: It might not be the same position. Position shouldn't matter in a `Map` structure since you do lookups by keys. If position is important to you, then you should consider moving the values to a different structure like `LinkedHashMap`